# PHP saving zero (0) value to MySQL error when using for

Tags: php

I have a form and I have many values. When I am trying the save these values to the MySQL, it doesn't save the zero values which are coming from form.
Here is my codes.

```
for($i=0;$i<count($cevap_deger);$i++){
  $cevapkontrol = trim($cevap_deger[$i]);
  if(!empty($cevapkontrol)){
    $sorgu = mysql_query("insert into CRM9001(CRM9107,CRM9102,CRM9103,CRM9105,CRM9109,CRM9108) values ('".$cevap_deger[$i]."','".$sinav_id[$i]."','".$bolum_id[$i]."','".$soru_id[$i]."','".$birey_id[$i]."','".$kullanici_id[$i]."') ");
    header("Refresh: 0; url=dashboard.php");
  }
}
```

It saves other values but only 0 it doesn't save. I tried this also;

```
for($i=0;$i<=count($cevap_deger);$i++){
```

If you help me I will be very glad.

Comment: Does the 0 index value pass the `if(!empty($cevapkontrol)){` validation?

Comment: Zero values for what variable?

Comment: What does or doesn't happen exactly? Errors? Different values? Just doesn't do anything? Please be as specific as possible.

Comment: Don't use `empty` there, it's pointless at that point. [The Definitive Guide To PHP's isset And empty](http://kunststube.net/isset/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[php.net](http://php.net/empty) says:

The following things are considered to be empty:

```
"" (an empty string)
0 (0 as an integer)
0.0 (0 as a float)
"0" (0 as a string)
NULL
FALSE
array() (an empty array)
$var; (a variable declared, but without a value)
```

note that you insert data into the database only if `$cevapkontrol` is not `empty` as in `if(!empty($cevapkontrol)){}` and 0 considered to be empty as mentioned

Answer (score 0):

0, false and loads of other values are [considered empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php).

Don't use the `empty` function. It sucks, because it considers all kinds of values empty that a normal person wouldn't consider empty.

Comment: `empty` does not suck. `empty` is shorthand for `!isset($var) || $var == false`. In other words, it's a normal boolean comparison rolled in with error suppression for non-existing variables. If you even dislike the boolean rules in PHP, it's simply not your language.

Comment: very thanks for your quick help. i removed empty function and the problem is solved.

Comment: @deceze I do dislike the non-strict boolean comparisons in most cases, yes. The value that is checked, is the result of the `trim` function. Since this is a string, you can check `if ($var === '')`. That way, you have a strong typed evaluation that checks exactly what you want and *only* what you want. It eliminates the risk of false positives and it shows that you actually understand the code you have written. PHP is like Visual Basic: you can write great code using it, but it makes it very easy to write crap. It's a challenge I gladly accept, and I try to convince others as well.

Comment: Absolutely fair enough, but that's no reason to call `empty` names. You should explain about the boolean comparison rules instead of just saying that `empty` sucks. If the OP replaces the code with `if ($cevapkontrol)` instead, nothing will change.

Comment: @deceze That's right. I wouldn't do that either, preferably not even for booleans, where I think `... === true` is the safer check. But you are right that my answer could do with a little less name calling and a little more thorough explanation of *why* I think it sucks. ;) I hope these comments have added that explanation. To summerize: I think in general weak typed comparisons (including functions like empty) are bad, because you will easily get 'false positives', leading to unexpected results. This question is a perfect example of that happening.

Comment: Personally I'm happy with the dynamic typing, you just need to learn the rules once. `if ($bool === true)` is pretty unnecessary IMO; if `$bool` is already a boolean, it's already a boolean. Why an additional check to produce yet another boolean? Why not `$bool === true === true` to make really sure? And if your `$bool` is not a boolean, then you have a bug which needs fixing. Oh well, don't want to incite a holy war... ;)